# How to use startsWith in a JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops, startswith

I'm new to programming and I'm starting with JS and I have to use a nested for loop followed by a startsWith() string method to print names started with 'M' to the console, like so:

> It's time to print all the names starting with 'M', again. Only this time use a much cooler nested for loop. Just a tip: you already know some string methods which will help you with this task. One we've never talked about is startsWith(). Can you guess what it does?
>
> ```
> var filmCharacters = [
>         ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],
>         ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'],
>         ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],
>         ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']
>     ];
> ```

```js
var filmCharacters = [
  ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],
  ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'],
  ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],
  ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']
];
for (var i = 0; i < filmCharacters.length; i++) {

  for (var j = 0; j < filmCharacters[i].length; j++) {

    if (filmCharacters[i][j].startsWith('M') == true) {
      console.log(filmCharacters[i][j]);


    }

  }
}
```

This is what I came up with and it prints all the names started with 'M' to the console, but it keeps saying this:

> Code is incorrect
>
> The condition of the if statement is incorrect. Make sure you're accessing the right element of each array and you're using the method we suggested correctly.

What can I try next?

Comment: When you say "it keeps saying this", what is saying that? Your code does not include those strings. I wonder if you are sending your code to an online submission service, and have forgotten to include that important detail. If so, please give details of that service, since readers do not have access to it.

Comment: Please use useful and informative titles here. "Can you help me with this?" is not useful - imagine if all 20 million questions were so named! This would make it much harder for future readers to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you need to use

```
filmCharacters[i][j].startsWith('M')
```

whithout any additionally check for being `true`. [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) returns a boolean value.

```js
var filmCharacters = [['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'], ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'], ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'], ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']];

for (var i = 0; i < filmCharacters.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < filmCharacters[i].length; j++) {
        if (filmCharacters[i][j].startsWith('M')) {
            console.log(filmCharacters[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it :)